# /Index.jsp automatically append on submit click

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I have facing issue at prodURL automatic append /index.jsp.
locally it's working.

http://localhost:8080?service=test&method=demo&image.x=26&image.y=12&image=submitForm

http://produrl/index.jsp?service=test&method=demot&image.x=26&image.y=12&image=submitForm
from tag

Comment: Check whether your context path remains similar in both cases or not?

Comment: It's same in both cases

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and update your question then. In short: **show your code**.

Comment: Add your web.xml